# Webpack 4 Extracted SCSS Hot-Reloading w/ Dev-Middleware

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-middleware, webpack-hot-middleware, webpack-4

I would like to use webpack-hot-middleware to work(hot reload) on extracted css files when using webpack-dev-middle with express server.

> It works fine with webpack-dev-server.
>   But I want to use it with express.

**server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');

const app = express();
const config = require('./webpack.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(config);

app.set('view engine', 'pug')

// Tell express to use the webpack-dev-middleware and use the webpack.config.js
// configuration file as a base.
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}));
// HMR
app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler, {
  log: console.log,
  path: '/__webpack_hmr',
  heartbeat: 10 * 1000
}));
// Render/serve HTML
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('layout')
})

// Serve the files on port 3000.
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!\n');
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware')
const hotMidConf = 'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=20000'

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    bundle: [hotMidConf, './src/index.js'],
    style: [hotMidConf, './src/style.scss']
  }, 
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'style.css'
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'extract-loader',
            options: {
              publicPath: './'
            }
          },
          {loader: 'css-loader'},
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')]
            } 
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ]
}
```

Everything else works, when I build I get the css file from the scss. I believe `style-loader` is what makes this work for when it is not being extracted but doesn't seem to do anything when I try it with it.

I have found a lot of answers using extract-text-webpack-plugin but this does not work with webpack 4 as far as I can tell... So I am using extract-loader with file-loader.

Comment: I have same issue! How did you solved it?